# Is there a better way to see MySql statements with parameters in C# using Visual Studios debugger?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, parameterized-query

I have recently been changing some C# programs to add proper parameterizing to some MySQL statements that had originally been written with concatenated strings. Invariably, I've run into some problems with my statements and I can't find a way to directly see the complete MySQL statement with parameters applied other than this workaround that I have where I pass the MySQL command to this:

```
private string getMySqlStatement(MySqlCommand cmd)
{
    string result = cmd.CommandText.ToString();
    foreach (MySqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        string addQuote = (p.Value is string) ? "'" : "";
        result = result.Replace(p.ParameterName.ToString(), addQuote + p.Value.ToString() + addQuote);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a more proper way to see the full statement with parameters applied. Reading up on this, it looks like the parameters aren't actually applied until it reaches the server - is this correct? In that case, I suppose I can stick to my function above, but I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do it.

Note: I am just using this function for debugging purposes so I can see the MySQL statement.

Comment: If prepared statements are not emulated then the parameters are applied server side, so you cannot see it in your client because it never was there.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports two protocols for client/server communication: text and binary. In the text protocol, there is no support for command parameters in the protocol itself; they are simulated by the client library. With Connector/NET, the text protocol is always used, unless you set `IgnorePrepare=true` in the connection string and call `MySqlCommand.Prepare()` for each command. So it's most likely the case that you are using the text protocol. This is good, because it will be easier to log the actual statements with parameters applied.

There are three ways to view the statements being executed:

#### Use Connector/NET Logging

Add `Logging=true` to your connection string and create a `TraceListener` that listens for the `QueryOpened` event. This should contain the full SQL statement with parameters interpolated. Instructions on setting this up [are here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing-mysql.html).

#### Use MySQL Server Logging

Enable the [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) on your server to see all queries that are being executed. This is done with the `--general_log=1 --general_log_file=/var/path/to/file` server options.

#### Packet Sniffing

If you're not using `SslMode=Required` (to encrypt the connection between client and server), then you can use WireShark to capture network traffic between your client and the server. WireShark has MySQL Protocol analysers that will inspect MySQL traffic and identify command packets (that contain SQL queries). This option is ideal if you aren't able to modify your client program nor change server logging settings.